# OL3: How to clear the cache of a ImageWMS layer while waiting for updateParams to return an updated layer

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

When calling source.updateParams() on an ImageWMS in OpenLayers 3, the current layer does not immediately clear, it waits for the new parameters to successfully return a result before removing the current image and replacing it with the new result. I am looking for a way to clear the current cached image out immediately so that the user doesn't see the old image while still waiting for the new one. I have tried turning the visibility off and then back on but that does not work. I have tried the various methods

```
source.dispatchEvent('change')
source.changed()
source.setImageLoadFunction(source.getImageLoadFunction())
```

but none of them have worked. The only way I have been able to simulate what I am looking for is to set the opacity of the layer to 0 as soon as the user updates the params and then turn the opacity back on

```
theimageloadend
```

event from the source.

Answer (score 0):

In OL6:

```
layer.renderer_.image_ = null;
```